# Send PDFs by email

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, django-views

I'm using djago easy pdf to show pdfs in my app but now I want to send the file by email using EmailMessage but I don't know how I can do it.

This is part of my code to send the html:

```
email_body = render_to_string(
    'mails/supplier_receipt_html.html',
    {'data': data, }
)
msg = email_body
headers = {'Reply-To': "contacto@comuna18.com"}
TO = 'mauricio.munguia@comuna18.com'
mail = EmailMessage(subject, msg, 'contacto@comuna18.com', [TO], headers=headers)
mail.content_subtype = "html"
mail.send()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types).

So you will have something like:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

msg = EmailMultiAlternatives('Your Subject','', "<from_email@x.com>", ["to_email@x.com", ])
html_content = "<p>Email with PDF file!</p>"
file_to_be_sent = ContentFile("your_pdf.pdf")
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
msg.attach("Your_Pdf.pdf", file_to_be_sent, "application/pdf")
msg.send()
```